# how do i get codenameone to use java.io.bufferedreader

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use `java.io.BufferedReader` in Codenameone. However I get this error when I compile

```
/Users/jamesagada/NetBeansProjects/reportYa/src/com/apiomat/frontend/Datastore.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BufferedReader
location: package java.io
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

Samething for `ObjectOutputStream`

Answer (score 2):

Codename One doesn't support either one of these classes at the moment. All streams in Codename One are buffered by default so you don't need the buffering features of buffered reader. To use a reader you can use `InputStreamReader` which is pretty close.

Object serialization isn't supported and neither is reflection since these features would prevent obfuscation and force packaging the whole VM essentially destroying application performance completely. So no `ObjectOutputStream`. You can get equivalent functionality through the Object externalization API available both in `Storage` and in the IO `Util` class, see the developer guide section on externalization.